# Wpf UserControl without xmlns:xxx reference

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to reference in XAML a user control like if it was just other normal control without the reference of a local:SomeUserControlName?

Example:
Instead of

```
<local:MyUserControl Prop1="" Prop2=""/>
```

I want to do

```
<MyUserControl Prop1="" Prop2=""/>
```

Like if it was just another control like a textblock or other....

I already tried the custom assembly xmlDef but is not working

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", 
    "AssemblyName")]
```

Comment: Note also that it is very bad form to dump your own code into the same XML namespace as already exists for other component areas, for the same reason that it would be bad form to declare all your user code in e.g. the `System` namespace. The namespaces are there for a reason. You may find that if you use one or two letters for your XML namespace names, you won't find it so inconvenient to use and declare namespaces for your types. E.g. use `l:` instead of `local:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlnsDefinition` is intended for XAML controls from a foreign assembly. It can't be used for controls in the same assembly because the XAML compiler needs to know about the controls beforehand.

Moving your custom controls into a separate project would allow you to use `XmlnsDefinition` references, because it would compile separately.