# Is there a clean way to replace a common control (e.g. CheckBox) with a custom descendant?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have created custom replacements for several built-in controls, such as `CheckBox` and `RadioButton`. These are not just new templates/styles for the existing controls but new descendant classes that provide some additional functionality (but no new properties). I'm now wondering whether I will have to go through all my views and replace all instances of `<CheckBox ... />` with `<controls:MyCheckBox ... />` and add the relevant namespace where necessary or whether there is an easier way.

I guess I could do something like the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <controls:MyCheckBox Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                     Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                     Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                     IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"
                                     and so on... />
            <ControlTemplate />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...but that feels kinda hacky... Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: "IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"" - TemplateBinding is OneWay, so this binding is likely needs to be changed.

Comment: I would say "go through all my views and replace all instances". do it once and live happilly afterwards. (but conside edge cases like DataGridCheckBoxColumn). you can also use xmlns hack to avoid "controls:" prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516533/wpf-usercontrol-without-xmlnsxxx-reference

Comment: @ASh : Those turned out to be very useful comments, both of which I would probably have overlooked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm now wondering whether I will have to go through all my views and replace all instances of <CheckBox ... /> with <controls:MyCheckBox ... /> and add the relevant namespace where necessary or whether there is an easier way.

Find and replace all occurances of `<CheckBox ...` with `<controls:MyCheckBox ...` across all of your XAML markup files is probably the easiest and most correct solution to replace the built-in control with your custom one.

Replace all is the cleaner and easiest way of doing this. Press <kbd>CTRL> + H</kbd> in Visual Studio and select `Current Project` and then compare the modifed files.

Comment: While it was a little more involved than this (apart from having to add the namespace, most of the existing controls also had an explicit `Style`-attribute that needed to be removed), this is essentially the solution I now went with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can neaten up the templating somewhat.

Say I have a MyCheckBox which inherits from checkbox.

I can make it use the checkbox template:

```
    public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
    {
        static MyCheckBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CheckBox)));
        }
    }
```

Then when I use MyCheckBox it will look very much like a checkbox. This works because every control has a default style which sets it's template.  That default style uses the type of the control as a key and hence x:Type CheckBox is the key of the checkbox style.

That doesn't get round an xmlns reference to your custom control library.

```
        xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <cc:MyCheckBox/>
    </Grid>
```

I think there is a rather dirty way you could use to avoid declaring an xmlns.

The wpf controls are referenced by the line

```
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

You can tell the compiler your controls are part of that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

https://paulstovell.com/xmlnsdefinition/

I would not recommend this though and maybe you could just do a replace all to change your controls.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't yet aware of the `DefaultStyleKey` override mechanism (or if I was, I had forgotten about it again). I always did this in XAML so far. However, my controls do need their own style so it doesn't really help me here. And I agree that hacking the namespace doesn't sound like a good idea.